# IntelliJ UnitTests Kotlin and Java with same name

Tags: maven, kotlin, intellij-idea

We have got a project from our university where they have created empty Java and Kotlin classes for us to add our code and some UnitTests to check if we have completed the assignments. I've been put in the Kotlin class and thus have to solve the problems in Kotlin and ignore Java. My problem now is that the UnitTests execute the Java code and not Kotlin.

For example:
Java Class:

```
package string;
public class Arrow {

    public static String arrow(int length, boolean doubleEnded, boolean doubleLine) {
        // TODO Implement the method
        return "java";
    }
}
```

Kotlin Class:

```
    @file:JvmName("Arrow")

package string

// TODO Implement the function
fun arrow(length: Int, doubleEnded: Boolean, doubleLine: Boolean): String{
return "kotlin";
}
```

UnitTest and Result:

```
package string;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class ArrowTest {

    static final int NBR_TESTS = 20;

    @Test
    void arrow0() {
        Assertions.assertEquals("", Arrow.arrow(0, true, true));
        Assertions.assertEquals("", Arrow.arrow(0, false, true));
        Assertions.assertEquals("", Arrow.arrow(0, true, false));
        Assertions.assertEquals("", Arrow.arrow(0, false, false));
    }
}


org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :
Actual   :java
```

What do I have to do so that the UnitTests execute the Kotlin code and not Java?
They told us we should not change anything in the tests.

Comment: Just an idea: put Java and Kotlin sources into different sourcesets (e.g. in gradle), and make your tests explicitly depends on the sourceset with kotlin. Edit: or, sorry, it's a maven thing :-). Ok, you can set the `sourceDirectory` to something different than `src/java`, e.g. to `src/non-existent`

Comment: @user3159253 Thank you very much! Changing the sourceDirectory did it for me

Answer (score 0):

As @user3159253 commented changing the sourceDirectory did it for me.
I opened the module settings and removed Java as a source and added Kotlin.